# Why do libraries targeting .Net Standard need Microsoft.Csharp

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I recently noticed that if I want to download a package from nuget for a library that targets .Net Standard, the dependencies for .Net Standard in most cases list Microsoft.Csharp package. However, if the library targets .Net Framework Microsoft.Csharp does not need to be installed. Why is this necessary for .Net Standard libraries and what is it used for. I understand Microsoft.Csharp provides support for compilation and code generation, including dynamic, using the C# language but I couldn't find any hints on what it's specifically used for.

Comment: You'd better dig from exactly where `Microsoft.CSharp` is pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because the `dynamic` keyword requires C# compilation.